# Android Swipe refresh layout issue

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have two textviews and one floating action button, and a listview.
Currently I am able to use swiperefreshlayout for listview but I want it to use for whole view i.e. when i swipe down from the top of the activity, the listview should be updated in background. 
Can anyone help me please.
This is my current xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_customer_name"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_floating_btn_add_ticket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_customer_name" />                             


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_tickets_activity_floating_btn_add_ticket"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_list_view_tickets"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SwipeRefreshLayout` on whole layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_customer_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="220dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_floating_btn_add_ticket"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_customer_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_list_view_tickets"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_tickets_activity_floating_btn_add_ticket"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And update your `ListView` in :

```
    @Override
public void onRefresh() {
    // Update Adapter for ListView here
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the circular thing which appears when we slide down is not visible, so do you have any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_customer_name"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_note"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_floating_btn_add_ticket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_tickets_activity_text_view_customer_name" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/view_tickets_activity_list_view_tickets"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_tickets_activity_floating_btn_add_ticket"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the circular thing which appears when we slide down is not visible, so do you have any idea why is it so?

Comment: you have to declare layout as 'mSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);    mSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);   mSwipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, android.R.color.holo_green_light,
    android.R.color.holo_orange_light, android.R.color.holo_red_light);
 '

Comment: No, still not able to achieve the required behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create layout with ListView like this, you have for ex. to add TextViews to header of ListView, cause RelativeLayout is not scrollable, that's why you can't have swipeToRefresh on it